# Lightweight Symmetric-key algorithm for bluetooth communications?

Tags: java, android, algorithm, security

In my app I've used AES algorithm  for WLAN communications, but now I'm transferring data through bluetooth I would like to get some security. The problem is that AES is too much "heavy" because it gives me blocks of more than 100 bytes - when I'm transferring less than 10 bytes - I would like to use something lighter, if it's possible.

Anyone knows a better solution?

Comment: AES in CBC by itself only pads to 16 byte blocks, which corresponds to 8 bytes on average per message. How do you get >100 bytes?

Comment: And using AES in CTR mode has no overhead at all.

Comment: You need nonce/IV for CTR mode and must transfer it with data. There is no padding, but still overhead.

Comment: @MisterSmith what's the difference between CBC and CTR mode?

Comment: CBC modifies the way the current block is encoded depending on the output of the previous block. CTR essentially builds a stream cypher from a block cypher, such as AES. Stream cyphers are much easier to misuse than blockcyphers, in particular you have to be careful to never ever reuse a key-nonce pair.

Comment: @blaze I was thinking about per-packed overhead, not per connection overhead. CBC needs to pad each packet to a full block, whereas when you encrypt with a stream cypher you can cut where ever you want without running into problems.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, but I'm not understanding the following and its probably from there I have the problem. Let's say I have a string with 100 chars/bytes. And I want to encrypt it using AES-128 bit in CBC Mode. The resulting encrypted byte array have 16 bytes or 96 because? (multiple of 16) Because the second situation it's what is happening to me. I'm getting many blocks of 16 bytes, in this moment, based in what you are stateing, I'm not sure if it's supposed. My code it's here: 
http://pastebin.com/tLCTQpY5

Comment: You'd get the next multiple of 16, which is 112 in this case. CBC pads to the next full block. But why are you using `NoPadding` mode?

Comment: Can't you just throw SSL/TLS at the problem? Yes it has a bit more overhead, but it's written by experts and mitigates a number of attacks your own code will be vulnerable to.

Comment: Your current code lacks IVs, has no integrity checks, allows replay attacks, has no MITM protection at all, and probably half a dozen more issues I didn't think of.

Comment: @CodeInChaos in response to your question, that's how I get results of more than 100 bytes. Returning to my original question, I wonder if I there's any symmetric algorithm which can compress the information. Just a dream? By the way, as you should know I cannot place a string with 100 chars because I get "data not block size not aligned". There's any trick to circumvent this situation? (besides manually complete the block). Use padding? EDIT: Is it normal that my code has issues, I'm still trying to make it work, not completing it. However, how can I prevent Man in the middle attacks?

Comment: @Tiago you've chosen to use no padding(`AES/CBC/NoPadding`). Use padding to avoid this problem. But you get at most 16 bytes of overhead per packed using CBC without IV. So you still didn't explain how you got from <10 byte plaintext to >100 byte cyphertext.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I was misunderstood. I didn't get from 10 byte plaintext to 100 byte cypher text. I was getting Z plain bytes to Z*2 cypher text, which was odd, but I recoded from zero and now it's working as supposed. I'm also now using PKCS5Padding, for block size alignment. Maybe you can refer me some documentation so I can understand how to use IV. Thanks for everything.

Comment: @CodeInChaos Yes, there is no per-packet overhead until you have uninterrupted stream of packets, like in TCP connection. If packets can be lost or duplicated, CTR mode must be reset for every packet, going back to per-packet overhead. I'm not sure if this is a case for bluetooth communications, there must be different transfer modes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AES with 128-bit blocks. That's 16 bytes. Initializing for encryption goes like this:

```
//Generate a key
KeyGenerator KeyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
KeyGen.init(128);
SecretKey Key = KeyGen.generateKey();

//Generate init vector
SecureRandom rng = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
byte [] IV = new byte[16];
rng.nextBytes(IV);

//Initialize the encryptor
Cipher ci = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding"); //The spec might be different!
ci.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, Key, new IvParameterSpec(IV));
```

RC4 has known weaknesses.

Comment: From when and by whom is it considered "broken"?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rc4): "RC4 has weaknesses that argue against its use in new systems". Follow the link over there if you want details.

Comment: "has weaknesses" doesn't mean "broken". SHA1 also has weaknesses but there exist millions of perfectly valid X.509 certificates. And both SHA1 and RC4 are widely used in TLS.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer, but that's what I'm using basically - AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding.

Comment: This question, answer and its comments made me understand to use AES (altough in a correct manner). So, answer accepted.